# Convert JSON object to serialized JSON string

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization

Probaly a duplicate but can't seem to find a solution. Is there a way in objective-c to convert:

```
{
    "a" : "value1",
    "b" : 1,
    "c" : "value3",
    "d" : "value4",
}
```

to:

```
"{\r\n\t\"a\" : \"value1\",\r\n\t\"b\" : 1,\r\n\t\"c\" : \"value3\",\r\n\t\"d\" : \"value4\",\r\n}"
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by converting JSON object?  There is really no such thing. JSON is a STRING format. It is not clear what the input is here is it a JSON string in pretty print and you are trying to collapse it to JSON string that is on single line with whitespace characters preserved? Why do you care about whitespace (as this is actually not valid part JSON specs)? Really the two strings you show are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code to convert a JSON object to a NSString in JSON format.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:yourDictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *strJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope this helps you.